# Dynamically create compiled binary with go

Tags: dynamic, go, compilation, dynamically-generated

First sorry for perhaps a bad title - I imagine a lot of the difficulty I'm experiencing relates to not knowing the correct terminology for what I'm trying to achieve.

In Go, I wish to have a program which when run can dynamically create a secondary binary. To illustrate with a basic hello world example - in pseudo code since I don't know how to achieve it.

```
generator.go
-> Read in statement from statement.txt (i.e. "Hello World")
-> Insert this statement into the following program...

package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main(){
    fmt.Println([dynamic statement inserted here])
}

-> compile this code into subprogram
```

Whenever `go run generator.go` is executed a `subprogram` binary is created. Running this would output `Hello World`. Changing statement.txt to something else and executing `go run generator.go` again would once more create `subprogram` which when run would execute the new statement.

In summary

*With Go, how can I create a program which can dynamically create a compiled child program as output.*

Thanks.

Comment: Is this something that using [go-bindata](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata) will solve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you have 2 sub-tasks which together do what you want:

1. Perform a text substitution to acquire the final source code.
2. Compile the final source code into executable binary.

### 1. Text substitution

The first can be easily done using the [`text/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) package. You can either have the source templates as separate, individual files, or embedded in the main Go source (e.g. as `const`s).

You can build / parse the source code templates and get a [`Template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template) with e.g. [`template.ParseFiles()`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#ParseFiles) or using `template.New().Parse()`. Once you have your template, assemble (e.g. load from file) the values you want to include in the source template and execute it e.g. with [`Template.Execute()`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Execute). You have the final source now.

The `text/template` package gives you a powerful template engine which is capable to a lot more than just text substitution.

**Note:** There is also a Go parser implemented and available in the standard library at your disposal in the subpackages of [`go`](https://golang.org/pkg/go/), but using the `text/template` package is much simpler and looks it's enough and perfectly fine for your case.

### 2. Compile

To compile the final source into an executable binary, you need the help of the compiler. You can use the [`os/exec`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) package to invoke the compiler which will produce the binary. See the [`exec.Command()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command) function to acquire a [`Cmd`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd), and [`Cmd.Run()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Run) and [`Cmd.Start()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Start) to execute it.

Comment: A nice implementation of the compile step is available in Gomega: https://github.com/onsi/gomega/blob/master/gexec/build.go It's not complicated to write yourself, but it's helpful to see a good cross-platform example.